# The resource cannot be found. Requested URL: /Area/Controller/undefined

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am getting the error shown below. I am getting this error way before my code execution reaches return View() or return redirect to action.

I have areas set up.  I am also posting the area registration section to check if anything is wrong there.  I have checked spellings of folders.  Everything runs fine until there is any section that gets data from the database via Entity Framework. I am really confused as to what is causing this problem.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /Admin/Home/undefined
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET >Version:4.0.30319.18408

Home Controller under Area

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Show()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Login()
{

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(string rememberMe, string UserName, string Password)
{
    AuthenticateUser Authenticate = new AuthenticateUser();

    if (Authenticate.isUserAuthentic(UserName, Password))
    {
        //the error page is rendered here ..
        //even before reaching the return View portion or Redirect to action

        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserName, false);
        return RedirectToAction("Show");
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}

DBCONTEXT DB = new DBCONTEXT();

public bool isUserAuthentic(string UserName, string Password)
{
    bool Authentic = false;
    admin_users User = DB.admin_users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.user_name == UserName);

    if (User != null)
    {
        if (User.user_password == Password)
        {
            Authentic = true;

        }
        else
        {
            Authentic = false;
        }
    }
    return Authentic;
}

public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Admin";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Show", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
             namespaces: new[] { "ProjectName.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
        );
    }
}
```

Please let me know if there is anything else that I need to share in order to make the problem more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Change your default route in global asax because it is looking for "Index" method in your "Home" controller which doesn't exists.

change your action property from

```
 new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
```

to this if "Login" is your default page

```
 new { controller = "Home", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
```